# Se colorent de / d’un rouge

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> - Lorsqu’on lui adresse un compliment, les joues de Delphine se colorent **d’un** rouge pivoine.
> - Ce poète colorait toujours ses propos **de** cynisme ou d’insolence.

([source](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2026))

Si on efface le mot "pivoine" dans la première phrase, est-ce qu'il faut écrire *se colorent **de** rouge* parce qu'il s'agit d'une notion abstraite ou *se colorent **d'un** rouge* parce que "rouge" est un nom masculin ?

Comment: Il y a toujours **le verbe rougir**: Ses joues rougissent, mais son petit nez éventé vous a un air fripon (France, Bonnard,1881, p. 333). TLFi

Answer (score 2):

*Rouge* n'étant pas qualifié, on utilise la préposition **de** sans article:

> *Ses joues se colorent **de** rouge.*

Avec une couleur qualifiée mais indéfinie comme *rouge pivoine* (**une** couleur parmi toutes celles que l'on appelle *rouge pivoine*), c'est bien ***d'un*** :

> *Ses joues se colorent **d'un** rouge pivoine*

Si la couleur qualifiée est définie (précisément **la** couleur des coquelicots), on utilisera ***du*** :

> *Ses joues se colorent **du** rouge vif des coquelicots.*

---

> *Pour beaucoup d'apprenants de FLE l'omission de l'article après DE fait partie de ces quelques points de grammaire les plus difficiles dont ils essaient de percer la logique, mais dont le sens continue toujours à leur échapper, même après plusieurs centaines d'heures d'apprentissage du français. Le fait que la plupart des cours de français ne s'occupent de ce sujet central de la grammaire française que d'une manière insuffisante, ne fait que rendre la situation encore plus triste. Les deux messages que j'envisage de publier sur ce sujet ont pour but de sensibiliser vos élèves à ce point de grammaire essentiel.*
> [Source](http://fle-lexical.blogspot.com/2016/07/de-article-zero-premiere-partie.html)

Comment: Merci, je ne comprends pas, dans _Rouge n'étant pas qualifié_ "rouge" est une couleur, pourquoi il n'est pas qualifié ? Pourquoi on peut dire _se colorent **d'un** rouge pivoine_ mais pas _se colorent **d'un** rouge_ ? Pourquoi dès que l'adjectif est omis, _d'un_ se transforme en _de_ ?

Comment: Il n'est pas qualifié signifie qu'il n'est pas accompagné d'un adjectif qualificatif, que le nom de couleur est donc utilisé absolument. Ce n'est pas vraiment *d'un* qui se transforme en *de*, c'est plutôt que *un* se transforme en "article zéro" (disparaît). Après *de*, le nom *rouge* seul est tellement général qu'il se passe d'article. Ce n'est pas spécifique aux couleurs: *le champ se couvre de neige*, pas *de la neige* ni *d'une neige*.

Comment: Ah, oui, en raison de "se colorer **de**". Peut-être parce que _se colorer **de**_ + _**du** rouge_ = _se colorer **de** rouge_.

Answer (score 1):

On utilise toujours une expression qui modifie « rouge » lorsque l'article indéfini est utilisé sans idée d'opposition à une couleur dans des teintes autres que le rouge.

- d'un rouge vif, d'un rouge qui est précisément celui du coquelicot, d'un rouge sans éclat, …

Sans cette expression il faut utiliser une préposition. « De » est la  possibilité apparemment unique dans le langage courant, mais dans le domaine de la chimie  « en » est celle qui convient. ([en rouge](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22se+colorent+en+rouge%22&lr=lang_fr&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=NjFbYYW8GZGwa9SNl1A&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiFr7Ldm7HzAhUR2BoKHdTGBQo4ZBDy0wN6BAgBEEE&biw=977&bih=1008&dpr=1)), ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=se+colorent+en+rouge%2Cse+colorent+de+rouge&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cse%20colorent%20en%20rouge%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cse%20colorent%20de%20rouge%3B%2Cc0))

Le caractère abstrait d'un concept n'a rien à voir avec le mot grammatical que l'on doit utiliser pour le relier aux autres mots dans la phrase.

*Opposition*

- C'est un rouge et non pas un orange ou un jaune-orangé.

Comment: Merci. Il n'est pas possible d'écrire _Lorsqu’on lui adresse un compliment, les joues de Delphine se colorent **de** rouge_, sans adjectif ?  //  Donc, _Lorsqu’on lui adresse un compliment, les joues de Delphine se colorent **d'un** rouge_ serait incorrect ?

Comment: @Oreste Non, au contraire, c'est tout à fait correct sans adjectif ou avec. Seulement « un rouge » sans modification n'est pas habituel.